# Not able to call api from heroku

Tags: python, json, api, flask

Hello everyone i recently deployed a python api on heroku which returns some url and works fine but when i try to call that api in another python script either its not working properly or i am not doing it in the right way so please if anyone knows , tell me.
Here is the code i am using to call the api:-

```
import requests
s = input("enter url")
#this is the input i take which gets added in the url i get from heroku
url = "the url"+s
responses = requests.get(url)
print(responses.json())
```

Comment: What is the error in the flask api hosted on heroku. You can see then by going to more>view logs. Also  paste the relevant code and structure of your flask api directory

Comment: What's the significance of "the url"+s? It seems that you should instead just set the url to only s, as any url you pass into requests.get with "the url" will be "the urlhttps://....."

Comment: In other words, try changing the line   url = "the url"+s     to    url = s